# String variables concatenation

Tags: java, string, string-concatenation

I have few lines of code as following. Here my question is which one to prefer ?

```
public static String convertMapToString ( Map < String, String > map )
{
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder ( 200 ) ;
    for ( Entry < String, String > entry : map.entrySet ( ) )
    {
        str.append ( entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue() ) ; 
    }
    return str.toString()  ;
}
```

or Should I go with following because I doubt that appned statement above may create two more additional strings as a result of **`+`** operation
in each iteration.

```
public static String convertMapToString ( Map < String, String > map )
{
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder ( 200 ) ;
    for ( Entry < String, String > entry : map.entrySet ( ) )
    {
        str.append (entry.getKey());
        str.append (" = ");
        str.append (entry.getValue()) ; 
    }
    return str.toString()  ;
}
```

Comment: decompile both versions and look what the compiler did with them.

Comment: The second snippet is likely to generate less String objects than the first, so I would prefer it.

Comment: @Tom Agreed, my guess is that option number 2 is "better", because there is need to concatenate the strings, and the `StringBuilder` would have to loop over the same number of `char`. So option 1 seems to be the same as option 2, but with an extra unnecessary concatenation

Comment: @Tom I found no change in the decompiled code of both the versions other than casting key and value parts to String. Were you pointing to this or was there something else you wanted me to realize ?

Comment: Then the compiled code is equal for both versions, then it doesn't matter what you choose. But look, that the first version wasn't compiled to `str.append(new StringBuilder(entry.getKey()).append(" = ").append(entry.getValue()).toString());`.

Comment: I meant decompiled code was exactly the same as original code for both the versions.

Answer (score 3):

By conventional wisdom, for optimal  `Strings` concatenation  you should prefer the `StringBuilder.append` method, so that would be option 2 in your examples.

Note that according to [language spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1) even if do you use the `"+"` concatenation, the implementation *might* choose to optimize those into `StringBuilder.append` , but it's not guaranteed, so I would suggest always choosing option 2 if optimal execution is your first priority.

Comment: Thanks for that spec link

Answer (score 1):

For readibility: the first one.

For performance: the second one

The second code should generate less objects and so be faster and use less memory. (Although the compilers will try to optimice the code to use StringBuilders but, like @Jas said: it's not warranted)

Now, knowing that, use whatever you need or whatever you think that suits better in your case.

I usually use StringBuilders only in loops and String addition outside them.

Comment: But the used memory and all: is this just a wild guess because you think it might be so, or have you actually compared the compiled results?

Comment: You are rigth, @Tom, I've edited the response. It's SUPPOSED to be the same performance and the same compiled code but it isn't warranted. So if you want to be sure StringBuilders will be use you should put them yourself in your code or uncompile all the code you compile to check it (and obviously, if you change the compiler; again).

Because of that I StringBuilders inside loops and simple functions and string addition outside them.

Answer (score 0):

Version two is preferred, because version 1 creates a bunch of objects unnecessarily and will perform noticeably slower.

String concatenation is compiled to creating a new StringBuilder, calling append on it for each part, then calling toString.